# Undoing changes made to local file with git

Tags: git, github, commit, git-branch, checkout

I have two branches of my project: **master** and **live**. I made some changes to my local files and when i was done, i wanted to push the changes to **master**. I never knew the current branch on git was **live**. I ran:

```
git add .
git commit -m "integrated ckeditor to replace Froalaeditor"
git pull --rebase bonychicken master
```

It was at this point git spat out:

```
From github.com:Lord-sarcastic/bonychicken
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: changed debug to false
Applying: integrated ckeditor to replace Froalaeditor.
```

And then I lost all changes to my local files.

So far i've tried

```
git reflog master
git reset --hard HEAD@{0}
```

It doesn't work.
Neither does `git rebase --abort`

Answer (score 0):

> I never knew the current branch on git was live

In your case, `git reflog live`, since you seem to have committed on the branch named `live`.

Then you can read the commit SHA1 you just created, and `reset --hard` your live branch to said commit.

Comment: Just tried it, It displayed:
`HEAD is now at 1ed1449 integrated ckeditor to replace Froalaeditor.`
But my lost changes has not been restored.

Comment: It should display a list, including the commit before head was moved.